# Pyrebase cannot find an email

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, pyrebase

I was following the Pyrebase tutorial and I got it up and running for one user account. I added another user account to the code and now I'm getting an error saying email address isn't found. The user account has been added to the Firebase User, and given the same access as the first account.

I've confirmed that the account has been added to Firebase with the correct email and password.

user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("someEmailAddress@gmail.com", "Secret Password")

I'm expecting a return code of 0, stating it's connected successfully. However, I'm getting the error below:

raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=AIzaSyDgn6aURRvEDP-M738sy7oo0ubbNqqLXzY] {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"

Answer (score 1):

I have found my error. After adding the account under the Project Overview -> Project settings -> Users and Permissions tab, I forgot to add the account under the Authentication tab on the left hand side. Once that's added, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When obtaining the Endpoint from Firebase Auth REST API, pick the Endpoint for signup with email/password.
The error arises because the Endpoint is for sign in with email/password.
You will be performing a sign in operation instead of sign up hence the error email not found.